# How to use a variable inside of if statement in jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2

I receive a list(`categories`) from Python application which I iterate over. I would like to define a variable based on input from this list, concatanete it with a string and use it for a further loop. After concatenation, the string literal of `atom_type` refers to another list from an application.

```
{% for c in categories %}

{% set atom_type = 'atoms_' + c %}

{% for atom in atom_type %}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that, in the second for loop `atom_type` is treated as a string, and not as an object. How do you use `atom_type` variable to refer to an object(python list)?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the categories as a list of dicts, pass them to the template and use the groupby() filter:

```
<ul>
{% for atoms in categories|groupby('atom_type') %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}<ul>
    {% for atom in group.list %}
        <li>{{ atom.name }} {{ atom.weight }}</li>
    {% endfor %}</ul></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```